# binding too much textures (more than 100) causes error

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, wavefront

I have a code that renders objects in obj and mtl format (android - opengl es 1.1) For small objects (few textures) I have no problem but when the number of textures exceeds 30-40, I receive this in my logcat: eglLockWindowSurface failed to map memory at...
I load all the textures in `onSurfaceCreated` using `glBindTexture` and `texImage2D` (all to single texture unit). And bind them for drawing in `onDrawFrame`

What's the problem exactly? I searched for hours but couldn't find any solution for this situation except texture atlas. Since my company gives me the export files of blender/3dsmax I can't use this approach.
How I can avoid this error and work with this too many textures?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the individual textures *small*? If not, why do you suspect it is the number that matters, and not simply the total size running out of the available texture memory?

Comment: @Paul-Jan They vary from 1kb to 300kb in size (total size of 5.12mb). when I load only the first quarter of textures it's ok, but for one third, it gives the error I mentioned. I guessed may be it's the number that causes the problem.

Comment: @Paul-Jan Thanks man! It was the size of texture. I scaled them down. (below 4096kb) and my code worked. Is there a more efficient way for loading textures?

Comment: 4096kb? Just to make sure, we are talking actual width*height*4 size here, not filesize (= irrelevant)?

Comment: @Paul-Jan Ooo! so max texture size means that all width*height*4 parameters of textures must be below a constant, yes? any way my code works now, thank you.

Comment: Yes, and good. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only limit for loading and binding texture is max integer size! the limit was maximum texture size (depends on device)
If maximum texture size is 4096kB, it means you can't bind an image that has width * height * 4 greater than 4096,000. (4 is float size). so you must scale down your image.